Finding data after fixed period during first transaction
I have a list of users that made a transaction between 03/05/2024 to 06/05/2024 for example. However, I want to know for this list of users, what is be their transaction data (ie gmv, txn count) 30 days after their transaction between that period.
I have a list of users that I have queried on presto sql. However, I am struggling to find the correct syntax and logic for the second part.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
